# Touch event on position: fixed; element doesn't work correctly on iOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, css

This is a similar problem with [IOS 5 (safari) bug with HTML touch events on "position:fixed" div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809706/ios-5-safari-bug-with-html-touch-events-on-positionfixed-div)

Somebody said that this bug has been fixed. But, on iOS 8, I find it is only fixed when you tap and scroll the page SLOWLY.

Here is my codes:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <style>
    header {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 600px;
        top: 0;
        color: #fff;
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
        z-index:100;
    }
    .content {
        height: 10000px;
        background: url(http://placehold.it/350x150&text=Background);
    }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header></header>
    <section class="content"></section>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        (function($) {
            'use strict';

            $('header').on('touchend', function(event) {
                event.stopPropagation();
                $('<p>Tap on float content.</p>').appendTo('header');

                // hack 1
                var $temp = $('<div style="height: 20000px"></div>');
                $temp.appendTo('body');
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $temp.remove();
                }, 1);
            });

            $(document).on('touchend', function() {
                $('<p>Tap on UNDER content.</p>').appendTo('header');
            });

            // hack 2
            $('body').bind('touchstart', function(e) {});

        }(jQuery));
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

You can find the bug in these two different ways:

- fast swipe and scroll the page on the `<head>` area for several times.
- swipe on the .content area, then quickly tap on the `<header>` area before the page stop scrolling.

In both cases, sometimes you can find that "Tap on UNDER content." is output when you tap on the `<header>` area.

**Update:**

There is 3rd case:

- swipe on the .content area, then quickly tap on the .content area again before the page stop scrolling, then tap on the `<header>` area. In this case, the tap on the `<header>` area doesn't output anything.

I've tried the hacks, like "add touchstart event for `<body>`", "add temporary `<div>`". None of them works.

Any idea on how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

if you have an element with position:fixed and touch event doesn't work over it, try adding :

```
pointer-events: none;
```