# iOS 5 safari mobile fixed position

Tags: ios, ipad, anchor, css-position, scrolltop

I'm working on a content piece which has a fixed nav that scrolls down to anchor positions using

```
$('.buttons').click(function(){
  var anchorPos = $(this).attr('href');
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(anchorPos).offset().top}, 1000);
  return false;
 });
```

However im having the reflow issue where on the ipad the nav is only clickable once, and doesnt work after scroll altoght it works fine on desktop.

I have tried different solutions to no avail, including adding empty divs and trying to change width of the body. I have mocked up what im trying to do on jsbin.

http://jsbin.com/esaxuc/2/edit

Would be grateful for any feedback! thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Fixed position navbar only clickable once in Mobile Safari on iOS5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7826868/fixed-position-navbar-only-clickable-once-in-mobile-safari-on-ios5)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a duplicate question. 
See the original question and specifically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10030251/1118070)

Yes I admit it is my own answer, but since posting it, a surprising number of people have contacted me to thank me, so there is a good chance it will help you.

Good luck.