# Lightbox wont open in iPad Safari 4

Tags: lightbox

I got a very simple jquery lightbox that works fine everywhere except in iPad Safari 4.3.1 ! The lightbox wont open when clicked.

Here is the link :
http://jetransmetsamessalaries.fr/

Scroll down to < Pourquoi transmettre à ses salariés > and the lightbox is on the round stamp with the face of one man.

Comment: In fact I tested onto browserstack and it looks like the popup open but at the top of my scroll down page. So I could not find it. Looks like a position absolute/relative bug...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, fixed position is not supported in iOS 4. So we got to use js or other solutions of the same kind. See more info here:
http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/12/the_fifth_posit.html
[How to resolve position:fixed for a bottom toolbar on iOS (iPhone/iPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409601/how-to-resolve-positionfixed-for-a-bottom-toolbar-on-ios-iphone-ipad)
[Fix position:fixed in iOS 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8701515/fix-positionfixed-in-ios-4)